# wxPython - Widgets With Same Name?

Tags: python, wxpython

Why does the following code create 2 widgets, and not overwrite each other? How would someone reference the first instance vs second instance?

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "Test", (250,250), (250,250))
panel = wx.Panel(frame, -1)

textbox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", (10,10), (135,20))
textbox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", (10,40), (135,20))

frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: wxPython has another mechanism in place to hold reference to the object. Basically by having both have `panel` as parent, the first object is not deleted, but not accessible by `textbox` name anymore. You have to call `Destroy()` method on the object first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The widgets are created, then assigned to the name. The first one still exists, but it is difficult for you to access it as you have assigned a different object to the name. If you want to still access both of them, try:

```
textboxes = []
textboxes.append(wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", (10,10), (135,20)))
textboxes.append(wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", (10,40), (135,20)))
```

Now you can access each by index:

```
textboxes[0]
```

Or loop through all of them:

```
for textbox in textboxes:
```

Comment: Oh, that's how you'd do it. However, why do they overwrite? What if I wanted to overwrite one another and not create a new one?

Comment: Why would you need to overwrite it? You can just change the relevant attributes if you want to alter it.

Comment: Well I'm doing recursion so the same statement gets called multiple times over. Rather not have 5 instances of the textbox.

Comment: Then, unless you can rearrange your code to create the widget once, you will have to explicitly `destroy` as Fenikso says

Answer (score 1):

There is another reference to your `TextCtrl` objects so it is no deleted as you would expect. Your `panel` holds a list of all its children. To delete wxPython widget, you have to explicitly call its [`Destroy()`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#Destroy) method. So in your case it would be:

```
textbox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", (10,10), (135,20))
textbox.Destroy()
textbox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", (10,40), (135,20))
```

To be able to access both objects, you either have to do as @jonrsharpe suggests or you can use [`GetChildren()`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#GetChildren) method. However holding references to all your widgets in your application yourself is preferred method.